# Помогите разобраться, не понимаю, что значит подобная строка в коде

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

```
var someVariable = someClassInstance?.CallMethod();
```

К чему здесь этот знак вопроса, и как его можно применять на практике?

Comment: это говорит о том что `someClassInstance` может быть `null`, эта фишка появилась в C# 6

Comment: Для полноты картины напишу, что неофициально этот оператор называют "Элвис" (Elvis). Напоминает чубчик у известного певца.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`?.` - это новый оператор в C# 6.0. Называется null propagation operator (не знаю как будет на русском). Это -

```
var someVariable = someClassInstance?.CallMethod();
```

короткий вариянт этого кода:

```
var someVariable = someClassInstance == null ? null : someClassInstance.CallMethod();
```

Так же он обеспечивает [потокобезопасный вызов делегата](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#thread-safe-delegate-invocation).

Comment: вообще говоря короткий вариант не совсем верен: в тернарном операторе ветки должны иметь одинаковый тип (либо возможность привести к одному базовому типу), и, например, если `CallMethod` возвращает `ValueType` - то этот вариант уже не будет работать

Comment: @Grundy Так, вы правы. Хотя я не уверен, как написать иначе, если не знаем, что `CallMethod` возвращает. Например, `var a = null; if(b !== null) a = b.CallMethod()` не работает (Cannot assign <null> to an implicitly typed local variable).

Comment: тут скорее всего тип результирующей переменной всегда _nullable_ если `CallMethod` возвращает _ValueType_.

Comment: @Grundy да, именно так.

Answer (score 3):

### ?. — это [оператор проверки на `null`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

Это позволяем избежать NullReferenceException при вызове членов объекта.

В ранних версиях пришлось бы писать что-то вроде:

```
if (someClassInstance != null)
{
    someClassInstance.CallMethod();
}
```

Это более-менее удобно если у вас один вызов, но в случае целой цепочки вызовов — утомительно.

Comment: Вы не совсем правы: код в вопросе не транслируется в приведенный вами код. Где же возвращаемое значение, если `someClassInstance == null`?