# Проверить существование объекта c#

Tags: c#

Делаю десериализацию массива json. Есть следующий код:

```
public class info
{
      public class step1
      {
           public string step2 { get; set; }
      }
}
json2csharp.info.RootObject csharp_info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<json2csharp.info.RootObject>(json_info);
```

Дальше я провожу десериализацию. step2 не всегда может существовать в json.
Как можно проверить? Пробовал так:

```
if(info.step1.step2 != null)
{

}
```

Сам массив json:

```
{"step1":{}}
```

Comment: Если версия c# позволяет  (больше 6.0 ) - то возможно [устроит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470646/213987) `if(info.step1?.step2 != null)` или `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.step1?.step2))` или даже IsNullOrWhiteSpace?

Comment: Сработал первый вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: Ну и прекрасно. Я закрою на дубликат, кажется есть получше на тему Null propagation.